# "we can not access the URL currently" Google Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I was able to pass a simple URL (thousands) 6 days ago to the vision client and obtain an output. However,right now, it is not possible. What changed? I don't like the idea of a simple workaround by downloading the data and then placing that as input.

What happened Google? Why did this changed? Should we move to Azure, AWS?

Anybody got the URL working without the workaround

Answer (score 1):

If you are using http URLs as input, it is possible that the Google crawling bot fails to fetch the URL you provided at that specific moment.

There are many reasons for this, for example:

The site of your URL is down, or it temporarily blocked Google bot, or it updated robot.txt to stop the Google bot to crawl URLs.

You can retry after a while, or you can download those URLs by yourself.

I guess if you try again today, it may recover to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use base64 encoded string instead of image URL.
I had the same experience to get a response from Google OCR API. It failed two or three times out of ten API calls. It really got me stressed because I got no clue.

Since I've changed my code to base64 accidentally, It worked well. 100% response. Never fail!!

Good luck!